# NoSQL Query Language, UnQL? N1QL? CouchBase, C embedded library

Tags: couchbase, sql++, unql, nosql

I'm investigating DocumentDBs, and I'm checking out the query side options.  I know nothing has firmly established as of yet, but have a few questions I've yet seen fully answered.

1. Couchbase dropped out of UnQL? and then developed N1QL?  Does this mean that they see N1QL as a more appropriate different query language? or does it extend what was set in UnQL?  Was anything actually formally standardized?
2. Is anyone allowed to implement N1QL?  Is it an open de-facto standard, vs. something patented in some way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regarding your first question...

N1QL is based on SQL, which is an ISO standard. Some of the language extensions like NEST/UNNEST and array comprehensions have been used and/or proposed elsewhere.

N1QL is not based on UnQL, but addresses some of the same needs with the advantage of being SQL.